# Apply a sequence to a table in access via vb.net

Tags: vb.net, sequence

Can someone complete the following code to allow a column in a temp table to be incremented by 1 each time (starting at 300 in this example). I don't want to use an auto number, I just want to apply a sequence to the column

```
    Dim conn As OleDbConnection = New OleDbConnection(FileLocations.connectionStringNewDb)
    conn.Open()
    'loop through the temp table starting at the last max test_id from tests and adding 1 to it...
    Dim getTmpTestsSql As String = "SELECT * FROM TESTS_TMP;"
    Dim adapter_tmp As New OleDbDataAdapter(getTmpTestsSql, conn)
    Dim dt_tmp As New DataTable("TESTS_TMP_")
    adapter_tmp.Fill(dt_tmp)
    Dim totalrows As Integer = dt_tmp.Rows.Count
    MsgBox(totalrows)
    Dim sequence_sql As String = "INSERT INTO TEST_TMP VALUES (@TEST_ID)"
    For i = 300 To 300 + totalrows
        Dim create_sequence_cmd As New OleDb.OleDbCommand(sequence_sql, conn)
        create_sequence_cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@A_ID", i)
        'move to the next row..................
    Next

    conn.Close()
```

Comment: This would be much easier to help you with if you shared which column you want to update. Do you have to do this as VB code? There is a fairly simple SQL statement that will do the same thing.

Comment: Column is just called 'number_' it's a completely blank column, can you show me the SQL solution?

Comment: VB code is the only way to do this, there's no concept of creating a sequence like in oracle in access (autonumber, but that's no good for what i require)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22041080/write-dataset-changed-back-to-access-database/22041348