# Write DataSet changed back to Access database

Tags: vb.net, dataset

I have the following code to alter the data, now I actually want to write said data back to the `TESTS_TMP` table in the Access database, how do I do that? I thought the adapter update did that but it doesn't?

```
    Dim dataSet As DataSet = New DataSet

    Using connection As New OleDbConnection(FileLocations.connectionStringNewDb)
        connection.Open()
        Dim adapter As New OleDbDataAdapter()

        adapter.SelectCommand = New OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM TESTS_TMP;", connection)

        Dim builder As OleDbCommandBuilder = New OleDbCommandBuilder(adapter)

        adapter.Fill(dataSet)

        'MsgBox(dataSet.Tables(0).Rows.Count)

        'Code to modify the data in the DataSet here.
        Dim id As Integer = 300

        For i As Integer = 0 To dataSet.Tables(0).Rows.Count - 1
            dataSet.Tables(0).Rows(i).Item(0) = id
            id = id + 1
        Next

        ' Without the OleDbCommandBuilder this line would fail.
        'builder.GetUpdateCommand()
        'adapter.Update(dataSet)

        Try
            adapter.Update(dataSet.Tables(0))
            dataSet.AcceptChanges()

        Catch x As Exception
            ' Error during Update, add code to locate error, reconcile  
            ' and try to update again. 
        End Try

    End Using

    MsgBox(dataSet.Tables(0).Rows(1).Item(0))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're calling `AcceptChanges`. and it is marking all of the rows as being unmodified, so they are never updated in the database. Remove this call.

Comment: I've tried removing that, doesn't do anything, the table in the access database still doesn't contain the updated data.

Comment: Did you check your database copy at `\bin\debug` folder?

Comment: Oh I see... I'm not using a local copy of the data set I'm just connecting directly to the database. I just want to do the above directly to the database?

Comment: Place `Dim objCommandBuilder As New OledbCommandBuilder(adapter)` above `adapter.Update(dataSet.Tables(0))`. This sould work

Comment: Within the try block? I've done that? doesn't do anything? What would that be for? Cheers

Comment: Yep. Put `MessageBox.Show(x.Message)` within `Catch` block. Get any exceptions?

Comment: Dynamic SQL generation for the UpdateCommand is not supported against
SelectCommand that does not return any key column information.

Comment: Ensure that your `TESTS_TMP` table consists of a primary key. update needs a primary key for at least one of the column in your database table

Comment: The field which I've updated in the for loop is the primary key, so it's technically blank at the moment. Grrrr.

Comment: I'm guessing the way round this now is exporting the data set to a csv and just import said CSV into the database. What a faff.

Comment: I've added a PK field as an auto number then ran it again, it works. Will have to do some playing around again to get the whole thing working as I need to now but thanks for your help it's half working as I need now :)

Comment: Congrats!! Glad to help.